# How to Create class diagram from Code?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, class-diagram

I have project under version control. I need to study code that is not mine. I am trying to find a better way than writing down the classes and their relationships in UML.

Is there a tool that does this automatically?

**Note:** The files are read-only so I can not use a tool that would have to modify them. I am working in Eclipse environment.

Comment: I've found the automatic UML tools don't help understanding existing code in any significant way.

Answer (score 7):

this program is very helpful (should work with no code changes)

> The ObjectAid UML Explorer
>
> http://www.objectaid.com/home

Comment: Tried to copy paste the installation but did not seem to work

Comment: Ive used this in eclipse and it was working fine.

Comment: This works like a piece of cake. Really helpful. I downloaded the eclipse plugin as per the instructions given in the above website. I am able to generate Class diagram for my whole package classes with much ease.

Answer (score 3):

Automatic UML diagrams are not going to be very helpful from existing java source code. You are going to notice that the code is a big mess where the Single Responsibility Principle is not applied consistently. Take a look at [inFusion](http://www.intooitus.com/products/infusion) to get some better views on your code. It can export a Famix model for use with [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org). That you can program to get the exact views you currently need.

Do you already have [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org) installed? It provides static views on the code.