# error starting Eclipse after installing an sdk

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit, eclipse-juno, samsung-smart-tv

After installing the Samsung Smart TV SDK on Win7 (64-bit) OS, i get the following error dialog box when attempting to run eclipse.exe (with using 'Run as Administrator' on the shortcut).

An error has occurred. see the log file PATH\FILENAME.log

The log file has the following:

---

```
!SESSION 2013-09-29 11:46:49.900 -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-09-29 11:46:55.657
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

---

My java version is (when typing:  java -version in a command prompt)

---

C:>java -version
java version '1.7.0_40'
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

---

I have added the following to the Path variable in the Environmental Variables already 
(to fix a previous error that occurred before the one i am writing about now)

---

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

---

Any advice here?

Answer (score 2):

check config.ini file in your eclipse installation path

This error happens because you deleted the config.ini file when you deleted the plugins. So, when it can not find configuration in config.ini when eclipse launches, then it uses a default configuration which does not fit with your OS. The following steps solve your problem:

Delete setting in configuration folder.
create a new config.ini file.
copy following setting and save.
restart Eclipse.
These are the settings:

```
osgi.splashPath = platform:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform  
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start, 
    org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start, org.eclipse.core.runtime@start  
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide  
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace  
eof=eof
```

Comment: after attempting the fixes mentioned above, this was unresolved.(didn't seem to be my issue, my install was vanilla and not altered)

after a new sdk install (which has the eclipse ide) i see that my eclipse.ini file has a couple of new lines that did not exist before.

new lines now present in my .ini:

-startup C:\Users\PATH\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar --launcher.library
C:\Users\PATH\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
again, no idea why this occurred but its worth a shot for a possible quick fix here.

Answer (score 0):

See:

["Unable to acquire application service" error while launching Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/i-am-getting-a-following-error-while-launching-my-eclipse)

and

[Can not start eclipse due to org.eclipse.core.runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774686/can-not-start-eclipse-due-to-org-eclipse-core-runtime)

They both seem to have solved the same issue.